# ford ranger...turn heater on...temp gauge shows cold?

Tags: ford, ranger

When heater turned on temperature gauge shows cold in my ford ranger 4 cylinder engine? Truck warms up normally and temperature gauge sets where it should set, but when I turn on the heater gauge backs off to cold.

Comment: Did you try bleeding the system?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? Do you mean cooling system?

Comment: Yeah, there should be a bleeder screw on somewhere on the coolant passages, you’d have to look at an online manual for your car or something like that to see it’s location, I don’t have time now but maybe someone else can explain to you the bleeding process, good luck!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Ranger? Is this the 2300 or 2500 I4 engine (or something else)?

Comment: 1997 Ford Ranger with a 2.3 liter 4 cylinder engine

Comment: 1997 Ford Ranger with a 2.3 liter 4 cylinder engine

Comment: Does this happen consistently no matter engine warm or engine cold?  If so I suspect you have a crossed wire somewhere.